# Spring Boot JPA LEFT JOIN in 3 tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, left-join

I'm using Spring Boot, and trying to utilize HQL to set up a LEFT JOIN between 3 tables.

The three entites I have are Usage, SubscriptionPeriod and Subscription. Necessary Hibernate annotation have been set in the entity classes.

- Usage and SubscriptionPeriod : Many to One (a SubscriptionPeriod can have multiple Usage)
- Subscription and SubscriptionPeriod : Many to One (a Subscription can have multiple SubscriptionPeriod).

***Goal : I want to fetch all the usages by providing a subscription id and usage has title 'NEW'. And, I want to do it in a single database request***

I have:

```
String hql =
                "SELECT DISTINCT u " +
                "FROM Usage u " +
                "LEFT JOIN u.subscriptionPeriod p " +
                "LEFT JOIN p.subscription s " +
                "WHERE s.remoteId = :remoteId AND u.title='NEW'";
```

Currently, there seems to be a syntax error around "FROM Usage ". It reads " can not resolve symbol Usage"

How can I achieve what I want? I am open to listen to alternative solutions as well. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the exact error message and when it happens (compile or run time). Also please provide a bit more surrounding code.

Comment: It was more of an IDE showing that it is an issue. I found a more simpler and elegant way. Thanks.

Comment: If you're thinking in terms of SQL you're doing JPA wrong.  The whole point of JPA is to force you to think in terms of objects, not relational.

Comment: Yeah, I am catching up. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I was probably thinking it in a probably more convoluted way. This `@Query` on a method works great. Hope this will be useful for somebody.

```
  @Query(
                "SELECT u " +
                "FROM usages u " +
                "LEFT JOIN u.subscriptionPeriod p " +
                "LEFT JOIN p.subscription s " +
                "WHERE u.paymentStatus = 'NEW' AND s.remoteId = :remoteId"
        )
  public List<Usage> find(@Param("remoteId") String param)
```